# admob (in a live wallpaper settings activity) crashes when clicked

Tags: android, permissions, crash, admob, live-wallpaper

I've made a live wallpaper. In the settings menu I've added admob. It loads ads just fine. 
I've used this tutorial http://irinaramazova.blogspot.com/2011/09/add-admob-adview-to-preferenceactivity.html.

But when i click an ad it gives me security exception saying-

```
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=ca.jvsh.livewallpaper/com.google.ads.AdActivity (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{2b3b5a38 3907:ca.jvsh.livewallpaper/10137} (pid=3907, uid=10137) requires android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1351)
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1374)
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at com.google.ads.AdActivity.launchAdActivity(SourceFile:257)
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at com.google.ads.i.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(SourceFile:134)
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:224)
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:331)
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
01-09 14:07:25.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the manifest file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ca.jvsh.livewallpaper"
    android:versionName="1.0.20100908.1"
    android:versionCode="1">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" />




    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <service android:name=".LiveWallpaper"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
                android:resource="@xml/livewallpaper" />

        </service>

        <activity android:label="@string/livewallpaper_settings"
            android:name=".LiveWallpaperSettings"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">

             <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">
                </action> 
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
         </activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

this is the live_wallpaper setting file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:title="@string/livewallpaper_settings"
    android:key="livewallpaper_settings">

    <ca.jvsh.livewallpaper.AdmobPreference android:key="adView">
    </ca.jvsh.livewallpaper.AdmobPreference>

    <ListPreference
        android:key="livewallpaper_background"
        android:title="@string/livewallpaper_background_title"
        android:summary="@string/livewallpaper_background_summary"
        android:entries="@array/livewallpaper_background_names"
        android:entryValues="@array/livewallpaper_background_prefix"/>
    <ListPreference
        android:key="livewallpaper_no_of_balloons"
        android:title="@string/livewallpaper_no_of_balloons_title"
        android:summary="@string/livewallpaper_no_of_balloons_summary"
        android:entries="@array/livewallpaper_no_of_balloons_names"
        android:entryValues="@array/livewallpaper_no_of_balloons_prefix"/>
    <CheckBoxPreference android:key="livewallpaper_shake"
        android:summary="@string/livewallpaper_shake_summary"
        android:title="@string/livewallpaper_shake_title"
        android:summaryOn="Balloons fall when the phone is shaked"
        android:summaryOff="Balloons fall from the top continously"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

This is admob preference class-

```
package ca.jvsh.livewallpaper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class AdmobPreference extends Preference
{
    public AdmobPreference(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
    }

    public AdmobPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.admob_preference, null);
    }   

}
```

Comment: SOLVED- REMOVED `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"` FROM `<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"> </activity>`

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t you try to use the AdMob tutorials?

http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html